# Calculating the individual transient behaviour of capacitors in series

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

I'm giving the circuit below, and am told that after a long time at 'a', the switch moves to 'b'.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I've already calculated \$v_0(t) = 80 - 40e^{-1000t} V\$. Now I'm asked to find \$v_1(t)\$, the voltlage of the \$0.2\mu F\$ capacitor.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that the capacitor takes a portion of the total charge of the two capacitors in proportion to it's capacitance. Thus, each capacitor takes a portion of the total voltage based on the ratio of the other capacitor and the total capacitance. So \$v_1(t)=64-32e^{-t/\tau}V\$.

However I'm not sure how to calculate the time constant. Could you help?

Comment: Both capacitors receive the same charge.

Comment: In series, capacitors have the same charge; in parallel, voltages are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Both capacitors will have the same time constant. And that will be:
$$t = RC_{eff} = R(C_1||C_2)$$
$$= 6.25 \times 10^3\times 0.16\times 10^{-6} = 1 ms $$

Comment: C1 in series with C2 not PARALLEL.

Comment: Ya but the effective capacitance is c1||c2 = c1*c2/c1+c2

Comment: I think it would be better to write that out clearly. When looking at C1|| C2 I usually imagine it is a topology definition rather then the formula like that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have found the time constant already. The same current flows through both caps, so the time constant is equal for calculating v1 and v2 (and for v0 - I assume by this you mean the total voltage across both caps).

R is 6.25kohm, C is the series connection of your two caps, 0.16uF. So your time constant is 1ms.

v1 and v2 will have the relationship: v1 = v2 * 0.8/0.2 = v2 * 4